# Cannot get Ajax working in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok, so i've spent the entire day trying to figure this one out- but i cannot! Here is my problem.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 & Razor. My goal is to do some BASIC Ajax. All i want to do is have a div on my page which gets updated by an Ajax link- to prove Ajax is working.

I think the problem has something to do with the script files i need to make Ajax work. By default, i didnt even have a scripts directory- so i created one, and found MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js- and added references into _Layout.cshtml inside the head

Here is what i've got:

In my _Layout.cshtml, i have the following inside my head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js">/script>`
```

In my HomeController.cs i have:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

Inside my About.cshtml file, i have the following:

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Ajax Test", "GetStatus", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="testtarget", HttpMethod = "Get"})`enter code here`
< div id="testtarget">Test Div</div>
```

When i compile the application, i can see the "Ajax Test" link- and the "Test Div" text.

When i click "Ajax Test", i get redirected to Home/GetStatus and a print out of the current time onto a blank page.

This is clearly not what i expected

Comment: Do you have jquery also included in the _layout? Because as the name implies `jquery.unobtrusive` uses jquery internally... And one more thing instead of "hardcoding" paths use `Url.Content` instead e.g.: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i just figured it out-

the MicrosoftAjax javascript files are no longer used post MVC2- instead, just add jquery and jqueyr.unobtrusive-ajax.min to your head- then the exact same code works :)

Answer (score 0):

For people looking at this post for answers, I would also add: ensure you have properly configured your web.config to allow the unobtrusive library to work

```html
<appSettings>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```